# NettyIO catch Connection Timeout

Tags: java, connection, timeout, netty, server

how can I catch a Connection Timeout? I want to notify the user that a connection timeout occurs. I tried using `option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000);` but if it exceeds this timeout, it doesn't seem to throw an exception.
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The ChannelFuture that is returned from connect(...) should be failed with an exception.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to simulate or cause a connection Timeout in netty? Would be practical to test things